Facing issue in list radio button selection in swiftui
code: with this code i am able to select each question multi check boxes but when it comes selecting radio button selection then i can able to select any one question options... if i select another question option then before question selection removes why? how to select each question options
struct SurveyQuestionsView: View {
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@StateObject private var viewModel = SurveyViewModel()
@State var id: String = ""
@State private var selectedOption: Int? = nil
@State private var selectedOptions: Set<Int> = []

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("(*) Mandatory Questions")
                .font(.calibriRegular(with: 15))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .padding()
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(0..<viewModel.questionsArray.count, id: \.self) {i in
                    questionOptionsCell(question: viewModel.questionsArray[i])
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(height: 3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.hexF4F4FC)
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    .onAppear{
        
        viewModel.fetchQuestionOptions(id: id) { status in
        }
    }
}
@ViewBuilder
func questionOptionsCell(question: QuestionSurvey) -> some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
        HStack {
            Text(question.question ?? "N/A")
                .font(.calibriRegular(with: 17))
                .foregroundStyle(.green)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
            if question.isMultiSelect ?? false {
                Text("*")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
        
        ForEach(question.options ?? [], id: \.optID) { option in
            HStack {
                if question.isMultiSelect ?? false {
                    Image(systemName: selectedOptions.contains(option.optID!) ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if selectedOptions.contains(option.optID!) {
                                selectedOptions.remove(option.optID!)
                            } else {
                                selectedOptions.insert(option.optID!)
                            }
                        }
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: (selectedOption == option.optID ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle"))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if selectedOption != option.optID {
                                selectedOption = option.optID
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                Text(option.option ?? "Option")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if question.isMultiSelect ?? false {
                            if selectedOptions.contains(option.optID!) {
                                selectedOptions.remove(option.optID!)
                            } else {
                                selectedOptions.insert(option.optID!)
                                print("selectedOption.... \(selectedOptions)")
                                
                            }
                        } else {
                            selectedOption = option.optID
                            print("selectedOption.... \(selectedOption)")
                        }
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .padding(.leading, 15)
        }
    }
}
}

o/p

edit: this is QuestionSurvey model
struct QuestionSurvey: Codable {
let queID: Int?
let question: String?
let isMultiSelect, isAnsMandatory: Bool?
let response: Int?
var options: [Option]?
}

tried like this still same issue
else {
       Image(systemName: (selectedOption == option.optID ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle"))
       .onTapGesture {
                            selectedSingleOptions[question.queID ?? 0] = option.optID ?? 0
                      }
      }


Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new Xcode project and reproduce the issue.

@BenzyNeez, yes one answer only can select but need to select that one answer in each question.. with my code i can select only one question.. if i select another question option then before question selection gone

@JoakimDanielson, some times when we get nil from backend so we made all model optional

If I understand correctly, the issue is that when you select an answer from the second question with radio buttons, the answer from the first question with radio buttons is de-selected.
I was able to reproduce this by running your code (after improvising all the missing parts). The problem is happening because the id of the selected answer is stored in selectedOption, which effectively means, you only have one radio button group.
To fix, you need to have one variable per radio button group. You could do this by using a dictionary, keyed by question id.
Assuming that each question has an Int id:
@State private var selectedSingleOptions = [Int: Int]()

if question.isMultiSelect ?? false {
    // ...
} else {
    Image(systemName: (selectedSingleOptions[question.id] == option.optID ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle"))
        .onTapGesture {
            selectedSingleOptions[question.id] = option.optID ?? 0
        }
}



same issue... added model and my tried code in post above... please have a look

@Swift You are still comparing the value of selectedOption in the ternary condition for the image name. Try copy/pasting the code from the answer.

okay got it... let me try

@Swift The definition of QuestionSurvey was one of the parts missing in the question. The point is, the value you write should also be the value you read. It looks you are using queID for writing to the dictionary, so try systemName: (selectedSingleOptions[question.queID] == option.optID ? "largecircle.fill.circle" : "circle")
